# Why does this happen with .row and .container-fluid in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Thank you for taking a look at my question which is: I'm trying to create two boxes that have the .row class and they are both in a .container-fluid wrapping. Whenever I do this there's a weird space on the right, I don't know if this is a margin that bootstrap adds but from what I understand .container-fluid is supposed to be full screen?

[image: <<IMAGE HERE>>]

The two boxes are yellow and white, the container-fluid is pink/magenta.

**CODE:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row" style="background-color: #EFF3CD; width:100%; height:350px;"></div>

 <div class="row" style="background-color: #FFF; width:100%; height:350px;"></div>
</div>
```

Any insights into why this is happening would be great and highly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you take the **width:100%;** off of the row elements?

Comment: container-fluid does have padding on either side, it just doesn't have a set of fixed widths: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1605.

Comment: @JonSG YES! thank you soo much! how dimwitted of me :D..

Can you answer the question so I can give you the check thingy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tom suggests, the width of the row elements is "determined" (via css) for you as part of the package. So when one sets the width explicitly even to 100% they are working against what bootstrap is doing.  The rose row is the required 30px wider than the blue.  I believe that would be true even without the bootstrap javascript but I added it for completeness.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="background-color: aliceblue; width:100%; height:50px;"></div>
  <div class="row" style="background-color: mistyrose; height:50px;"></div>
  <div class="row" style="background-color: aliceblue; width:100%; height:50px;"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your `width: 100%` property from `.row.` That class already sets left and right margins, which looks to be why you're having this problem. If you look at it in your browser's inspector, it should show you how the margins are drawn visually.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting margin for container-fluid:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0 auto;">
 <div class="row" style="background-color: #EFF3CD; width:100%; height:350px;"></div>

 <div class="row" style="background-color: #FFF; width:100%; height:350px;"></div>
</div>
```